# Release Note Management for .NET Applications

Tags: asp.net, tfs

My team uses TFS for source control and continuous integration.  I'd like to come up with a nice, clean way to show release notes to end users each time we deploy.  I'm curious what others are doing to manage release notes in an ASP.NET / TFS environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I put together a basic [release notes report](http://richardsbraindump.blogspot.com/2009/08/release-notes-report-for-tfs.html) (for TFS2008) that you may find useful.  Not sure if it's what you're after, but it works fairly well for me.  You can always take it and do what you want with it to make it more suited to your environment and neds.

Comment: You should be careful about deploying Richard's report. It queries the TFS operational databases directly (TFSWorkItemTracking & TFSVersionControl) - this is unsupported by Microsoft.  The supported way is to use the warehouse or the object model.

Comment: What Grant says it true, however since the information needed for the report isn't available in the warehouse there's little choice.

Answer (score 0):

Well I typically hold documents like that as part of the solution under source control, so that the document is versioned and tracked. From then on there are several options - one is to bundle it with the release (attach a link to the file to one of the projects and select "Copy Local" = true), or to embed it into one of the projects and use it in a popup - this can be done with the installer project or as part of the "About" dialog. Or do both.